# Python - a set of one type only

Tags: python, types, set

I want to create a Set class in Python, but unlike the set class that already implemented in Python, I want my set to contain elements of only one type. For example a set of integers, a set of strings and a set of any other user defined class.

Is there any way in Python to pass the type as a parameter to the class? or any other way to do it?

I was thinking about using dict to implement the set but dicts can contain elements from different types.

Comment: Sets are just dictionaries without values. You'll have to verify the types on any manipulation of the set; adding, intersections, unions, etc. Stating what type it should be in the initializer is but a fraction of the task.

Comment: i think the lack of static typing prevents such a feature.

Comment: And what are you hoping to achieve? Python is dynamically typed, and that is a *strength*. Why the attempt to remove that? There is a utility in the `array()` type, storing primitive types for fast operations and reducing memory footprint, but you want to support custom types too.

Comment: @njzk2: No, you can lock down a custom class and limit what can be added to the set to a certain extend, but I just don't see why you'd want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somethig like that?

```
from sets import Set

class MySet(Set):

    def __init__(self, iter, klass=None):
        if klass is not None:
            for item in iter:
                if not isinstance(item, klass):
                    raise Exception("Error")
        super(MySet, self).__init__(iter) 


if __name__ == '__main__':

    set1 = MySet([1,2,3], int)
    set2 = MySet([2,3,4], int)

    print set2.intersection(set1)
```

If you want a control of the type even in the methods like `intersection`, you should override the call for the generation of the new Set (`self.__class__(common)`)

bye